# Log output from bash script into log file and stdout while running from perl

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, debian

I have perl script

perl script (install.pl):

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Term::ANSIColor;
my $logfilename = "install.log";
open LOG,">$logfilename" or die "failed to open log file reason:$!";
sub logMsg
{
    my ($msg) = @_;
    my ($error) = $_[1];
    $msg .= "\n";
    print LOG $msg;
    if( $error ) { print color 'red' ;}
    {print $msg}
    if( $error ) { print color 'reset' ;}   
}
sub lampInstall
{
    logMsg("Installing apache2, php, and mysql db");
    # Install apache2 and mysql:
    my $cmdOutput = `./ubuntu-lamp-install.sh`;
    print LOG "$cmdOutput\n";
}
lampInstall();
close LOG;
```

bash script (ubuntu-lamp-install.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password test" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password test" | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install -y apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

The issues is that , when `install.pl` is invoked, it waits for long time and does not give any output information of what is being installed.I need it to change the perl script to display the output information from bash script(better if instantaneous) as well as log the output to log file. The script is written by someone else , I have very little knowledge of perl scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
open my $cmdOutut, "-|", "./ubuntu-lamp-install.sh";
while (<$cmdOutput>) {
    print LOG "$_\n";
    print "$_\n";
}
```

in your `lampInstall()`.

This is the new `lampInstall()`:

```
sub lampInstall
{
    logMsg("Installing apache2, php, and mysql db");
    # Install apache2 and mysql:
    open my $cmdOutut, "-|", "./ubuntu-lamp-install.sh";
    while (<$cmdOutput>) {
        print LOG "$_\n";
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: would you like to explain `open my $cmdOutut, "-|", "./ubuntu-lamp-install.sh";` ?

Comment: @sakhunzai Perl documenation already explains it quite well, please read it first. You could read it by `perldoc -f open`.